# Visual Studio 2010 library problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directx

Ok so I just installed Visual Studio 2010 and DirectX SDK *(DirectX Software Development Kit June 2010 9.29.1962)*, and I tried to make a simple program to test everything out. I've put in a source which works well on Dev C++, but somehow VS keeps giving me this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16
```

I know I have to link a library to fix it but it simply cannot be done!! I googled a lot and didn't find anything useful so far. Tried to #pragma coment it, tried to link it in project properties, tried and tried and failed...

So my question is: **How to link libraries in Visual Studio 2010??**

Comment: It cannot be done??  What force of nature is stopping you from linking d3d9.lib?

Comment: I have no idea lol... I link it(at least I think I do) but it keeps giving me the error.

Comment: Well, I have no idea either of course.  You'll have to describe what you did to make you think you linked it in detail.

Comment: well in Dev C++ I used project options to link libraries so I tried it out here too... I went to Properties>Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies and I added d3d9.lib... is that the right way to do it? I also tried #pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib") but it didn't do the trick either

Comment: You running on 32-bit mode or 64-bit?

Comment: That is correct.  Post your project to a file sharing site.

Comment: Finally figured it out... the problem was I copied the libraries from SDK into the VS lib folder while the VS was running... That way I guess VS thought there were no matching libraries in the folder(as there were none when it was started) and didn't link them... Just restarted it and it magically worked... I had no idea that could possibly make any difference :/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. try going to the Output category of the Link tab in the Project Settings dialog box, set the Entry Point Symbol to wWinMainCRTStartup.